# extendsとプロトタイプを使った継承に違いはありますか？

Tags: javascript

参考書とwebで学習でプロトタイプチェーンの勉強する中で `constructor` プロパティについての説明として、以下のような記載がありました。

> プロトタイプ継承している場合、constructorプロパティが示すものは、継承元のクラスとなる

そこで、以下の constructor プロパティを使った、二つのコードを見てください。

#### 参考書にあったコード

```js
var Animal1 = function() {};
var Hamster = function() {};
Hamster.prototype = new Animal1();

var hamster = new Hamster();
console.log(hamster.constructor);
//結果:Animal1
```

#### webにあったコード

```js
class Animal{};

//Animalから継承
class Rabbit extends Animal{};

//Rabbitをインスタンス化
const rabbit = new Rabbit();

console.log(rabbit.constructor); 
//結果:Rabbit
```

### ここで質問があります。

#### extendsはプロトタイプ継承のシンタックスシュガーではないのですか？

webのコードでextendsを使いAnimalを継承しているのrabbit.constructorの結果はAnimalだと思いました。

Comment: 可能であれば、参考にした書籍名やサイトの URL も質問中に含めてみてください。